# Can I Create a Partial View with Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

Using ASP.net MVC3 with C#

I want to create a partial view that uses a single database record so I have the View down fine but what controller would I create to actually create the LINQ query or do I need to do it in the View file?

The partial will display a random ad and be on every page on the site.

Comment: Keep your view separate from application logic. If the partial only needs to appear under special conditions then set a variable in your controller and check it in your view where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M.Babcock says, you really should keep the logic out of the *View* and into the *Controller* (or *Model* if appropriate).

I would pass the resulted data to the *View* either through a *Model*, or it little data then just pass it through the `ViewBag` (or `ViewData`).